# Encoding symbols from LaTeX in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, symbols, latex

I would like to solve a problem but I am not able to do it. Precisely I am creating figures and I should insert mathematical formulas. The first thing I do is to create a `.pdf` file from a `.tex` source and then edit it in Adobe Illustrator. I can change the symbols, but, for example, the square root is not perfectly viewable and in its place I see a rectangle with a cross. There is some strategy to solve this problem?

I have attached the related images created first with the LaTeX, and then edited with Adobe Illustrator.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need a specific mathematical symbols font for it.

You can make the square root from the **Glyphs Panel** using [Mathematical Pi Lt Std](https://www.fonts.com/font/adobe/mathematical-pi/lt-std?SiteId=62) font from fonts.com, and combining two characters:

[image]

Comment: I have now upvoted your excellent answer. I hope that my question is good and the prevoius my question.